# Is it possible to play Pokemon Puzzle League multiplayer online?

Tags: emulation, pokemon-puzzle-league

Is it possible, I imagine through some kind of emulator, to play Pokemon Puzzle League's multiplayer vs mode online? What would be required to set this kind of system up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, but it's very buggy.  Often, what you see and what your partner sees will de-sync, and it will look as if your opponent just lost on purpose.

BUT you CAN play Tetris Attack online via the ZSNES 1.36 emulator. (Tetris Attack is the Super Nintendo version of Puzzle League, but with Yoshi instead of Pokemon).

To easily find an opponent interested in playing Tetris Attack online, and to more easily connect to that opponent, download Hamachi, and join the Hamachi network called TetrisAttackOnline. Full setup instructions are here: http://bit.ly/TetrisAttackSetup